# htaccess 301 redirect for second level sub directory

Tags: htaccess, 301-redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a directory website with the following URL structure.

```
http://mywebsite.com/information/business-name/
http://mywebsite.com/information/business-name/product-names/    
http://mywebsite.com/reviews/business-name/
http://mywebsite.com/comments/business-name/
```

Now, there is a change in the business name and I want to change the URLs to these -

```
http://mywebsite.com/information/new-business-name/
http://mywebsite.com/information/new-business-name/product-names/    
http://mywebsite.com/reviews/new-business-name/
http://mywebsite.com/comments/new-business-name/
```

How do I 301 redirect the old URLsto new URLs in htaccess file?

Currently, I am temporarily using the following -

```
RewriteRule ^information/business-name/(.*)$ /information/new-business-name/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^reviews/business-name/(.*)$ /reviews/new-business-name/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^comments/business-name/(.*)$ /comments/new-business-name/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Is there a way to rewrite it in one rule as I just need to change `/business-name/` to `/new-business-name/` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To combine those three rules into one you can use alternation (with a vertical bar) in a capturing group and another backreference in the substitution:

For example:

```
RewriteRule ^(information|reviews|comments)/business-name/(.*)$ /$1/new-business-name/$2 [R=301,L]
```

`$1` is now a backreference to either "information", "reviews" or "comments".

Depending on your situation you could make this more generic:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/business-name/(.*)$ /$1/new-business-name/$2 [R=301,L]
```

This will match *any* single subdirectory that precedes "/business-name/", including "information", "reviews" and "comments".